# Error while Installing ruby2.1.5 from sources on freebsd 7

Tags: ruby, freebsd

I am trying to install ruby2.2 in in freebsd 7 i386, but it is throwing below error.
Can someone help how to resolve it
I

```
# make
    CC = /usr/local/bin/gcc48
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = /usr/local/bin/gcc48 -shared
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra 
             -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses 
             -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers 
             -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith 
             -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement 
             -Wimplicit-function-declaration 
             -ansi -std=iso9899:199409
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector 
              -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden 
              -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/i386-freebsd7.1 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,showflags -fstack-protector -pie
    SOLIBS =
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/gcc48
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=
/usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/i386-portbld-   freebsd7.1/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: i386-portbld-freebsd7.1
Configured with: ./../gcc-4.8.3/configure 
--disable-bootstrap --disable-nls                
--enable-gnu-indirect-function 
--libdir=/usr/local/lib/gcc48 
--libexecdir=/usr/local/libexec/gcc48 
--program-suffix=48 
--with- as=/usr/local/bin/as 
--with-gmp=/usr/local 
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/local/lib/gcc48/include/c++/ 
--with-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld 
--with-pkgversion='FreeBSD Ports Collection' 
--with-system-zlib --disable-libgcj 
--enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran 
--prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/man 
--infodir=/usr/local/info/gcc48 
--build=i386-portbld-freebsd7.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (FreeBSD Ports Collection)
compiling math.c
**math.c: In function 'math_log':
**math.c:466:9: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11
     d += numbits * log(2); /* log(2**numbits) */****
     ^
```

no stack trace because unwind library not available
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Comment: ffs who downvoted it? Anyway, have you tried to compile it with clang?

Comment: FreeBSD 7.1 has been unsupported for 4 years (since 28 February 2011). You're also trying to use an unsupported compiler (gcc 4.8.3) which may or may not work on FreeBSD 7.1 ... Your options are: 1) be satisfied with an older Ruby version; 2) update to a newer FreeBSD; or 3) spend a lot of time yourself in trying to fix this.

Comment: @user2422869 Did FreeBSD 7.1 even include clang? From memory, this was added in FreeBSD 8.

Comment: As others have pointed out: FreeBSD 7.1 has been unsupported for a very long time.  You'll get a lot more help if you use a supported or at least a more recent release.  You also don't mention if you're building "virgin" sources or from the ports tree.  The ports tree contains patches for known compilation problems.

Comment: It's from ports because it adds `--build=i386-portbld-freebsd7.1`. I'm fairly sure the ports tree removed FreeBSD 7 support a while ago, so that's unsupported as well ;-)